# When using emacs org mode. Pressing backspace in a head jumps to the top of the page

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Lets assume that I have something like the following

```
* Project Outline
** Foobat
```

And the cursor is on the `t` of `foobat` I want to delete the `t` by pressing backspace. When I press backspace, the cursor will jump to the first astrix at the top of the page. This is the astrix right before `Project Outline`. Why is this happening?

Comment: see what function the key is bound to with `C-h k <backspace>`. For me, that is `org-delete-backward-char`  which calls some other functions and may behave differently based on your settings

Comment: Sounds like something else that you are loading is interfering with the normal Org-mode key binding. If you don't see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. Or start with what @jenesaisquoi suggested - perhaps you can guess the culprit code from the name of the command bound to that key sequence.

Comment: I did `C-h k <backspace>` and it showed `paredit-backward-delete`